# ServiceMix (FuseESB) fails to find Camel javascript support when jar starts up

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, apache-servicemix, blueprint-osgi, fuseesb

When deploying a Camel route to FuseESB, as FuseESB tries to start up the jar file, it gives the following exception in the log:

```
Found initial references null for OSGi service (&(language=js)
(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.LanguageResolver))
```

This causes the bundle to enter a grace period for a few minutes, after which it times out and its status moves to failed. Note that I'm not using javascript in the application, but I assume it is loaded as part of loading Camel core.

Details of my setup:

- Code in question is written using an OSGi blueprint xml file to define the beans.
- Code is packaged as a jar, as opposed to an OSGi bundle.
- Code is deployed by being dropped into the deploy directory so it is deployed by the FAB deployer.

I believe I have the relevant Camel features installed.

Output from features:list:

```
[installed  ] [2.10.0.fuse-71-047] camel-script-javascript camel-2.10.0.fuse-71-047
[installed  ] [2.10.0.fuse-71-047] camel-script            camel-2.10.0.fuse-71-047
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around this by:

- reverting to a spring xml file to define the beans
- packaging the code as a bundle, not a jar

I still don't understand why the Blueprint version didn't work, but the question is now less urgent than it was.

Answer (score 0):

With FAB you should declare the dependencies to your Camel components in your pom.xml file, and use scope=provided.

See more details at: http://fuse.fusesource.org/bundle/overview.html